# scalajs regular expression with Unicode property \\pL or \\p{L}

Tags: regex, unicode, scala.js

Need a regular expression for a letter in any language. \pL or \p{L} work within Ammonite Repl 1.6.8 (Scala 2.13.0 Java 11.0.8)

```
@ "\\pL+".r.findFirstIn("abcßäöñ") 
res1: Option[String] = Some("abc\u00df\u00e4\u00f6\u00f1")

@ "\\p{L}+".r.findFirstIn("abcßäöñ") 
res2: Option[String] = Some("abc\u00df\u00e4\u00f6\u00f1")
```

But the Unicode property does NOT work in Scalajs (1.5.1), i.e. result None.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the target ECMAScript version, change it in the following setting:

```js
scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= (_.withESFeatures(_.withESVersion(ESVersion.ES2018)))
```

Also, you might need to add `val ESVersion = org.scalajs.linker.interface.ESVersion` in your *build.sbt*.

Then you can use

```
"(?U)\\p{L}+".r.findFirstIn("abcßäöñ")
"(?U)[^\\W\\d_]+".r.findFirstIn("abcßäöñ")
"(?U)\\p{Alpha}+".r.findFirstIn("abcßäöñ")
```

The `(?U)` flag is the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` embedded flag option that makes `\w`, `\s`, `\p{Alpha}` etc. classes Unicode aware. `[^\W\d_]` is a class that matches any word chars other than digits and underscores, so basically, letters. `\p{Alpha}`/`\p{L}` will match letters only.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Unicode not supported in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Since Scala.js 1.7.0, Unicode properties, such a `\p{L}` or its short form `\pL`, are conditionally supported. They are supported only with the following sbt setting:

```scala
scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= (_.withESFeatures(_.withESVersion(ESVersion.ES2018)))
```

(If using another build tool, please consult that build tool's way of specifying Scala.js linking options.)

With that setting enabled, the only `\p{x}` properties that are not supported are the ones where `x` is of the form `In` and where  represents a Unicode *block*. `L` is not of the form `In...`, so it is supported.

Reference: [the Scala.js documentation on regex support](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/regular-expressions.html):

> #### Conditionally supported
>
> [...]
>
> The following features require `esVersion >= ESVersion.ES2018` (which is
> false by default):
>
> - [...]
> - `\p{}` expressions where  is not one of the POSIX character classes.